# Docker info does not provide storage details?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I saw that docker is supposed to give us storage details such as storage  when using the command docker info as on  https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/#configure-loop-lvm-mode-for-testing

But when I run docker info I only get file system type and no information about storage pool, base device size etc.Please see https://i.stack.imgur.com/16IJM.jpg

Comment: Take a look at [Example](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/info/)

Comment: @Sam  Yes,I did - I used the same command as them , docker info.
But when it gets to the storage driver section , it does not have any information regarding Pool Blocksize or Base Device Size.